# How do you disable the global menu in digikam?

Tags: 11.10, menu, appmenu, digikam

I use digikam which suffers from a [bug that means the editor loses its menu after the first launch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-qt/+bug/778418). In 11.04 I could disable the global menu for digikam by launching it with:

```
APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1 digikam
```

However this appears to have stopped working in 11.10. Is there some other way to get an application to show the menubar in the window rather than the panel?

(Just checked and `APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1 gedit` does lead to gedit having a menu in the window. But maybe there is some other way?)

Comment: I don't understand what the question here is supposed to answer, it looks like you've filed the bug, what are we supposed to do now?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: I was wondering if 11.10 had changed the environment variable(s) it used to control how menus were displayed. I guess I could have made that clearer in the question.

Comment: Nope, nothing in the variable has changed. Though it looks like it's a specific problem with digicam. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is '..to disable the global menu in digikam'

What you've been doing previously is not disabling the global menu but enabling both the global & in app window menu. (which by the way should still work

To actually disable global on an individual **qt4** app's you use this in various ways

```
QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1
```

For opening digikam from a menu, dash, ie. thru it's .desktop, then you simply edit the Exec= line in it's .desktop or if using unity & a quicklist the Exec= in the quicklist entry. Example on digikam's .desktop

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kde4/digikam.desktop
```

Then use this as the Exec= line in the .desktop

```
Exec=env QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 digikam -caption "%c" %i
```

For starting from a terminal you'd do this instead (or create an alias

```
export QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1; digikam
```

For starting from Alt+F2  - a bit more complicated, probably not of interest here

As far as why you can't use your old 'both' method, not sure. If inclined to pursue I'd start by creating a new user, logging into it & seeing if it works there. If so it's something local to your user, you can track it down if desired with a little time & effort

Answer (score 1):

From subscribing to the bug, someone [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-qt/+bug/778418/comments/19):

> Today I removed the package "appmenu-qt".
>   All applications based on QT will start now without the global menu.
>   All other apllications are starting with global menu.
>   Digikam is working now, but I would like to have the global menu.